# How to add image in ListView android

Tags: android, listview

i would like to add images on my list view, and i have this code

```
package com.wilis.appmysql;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class menulayanan extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        String[] menulayanan = new String[] { "Berita Terbaru", "Info Item", "Customer Service", "Help","Exit"};

        //Menset nilai array ke dalam list adapater sehingga data pada array akan dimunculkan dalam list
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menulayanan));
    }

    @Override
    /**method ini akan mengoveride method onListItemClick yang ada pada class List Activity
     * method ini akan dipanggil apabilai ada salah satu item dari list menu yang dipilih
     */
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked
        // Menangkap nilai text yang dklik
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String pilihan = o.toString();
        // Menampilkan hasil pilihan menu dalam bentuk Toast
        tampilkanPilihan(pilihan);
    }
    /**
     * Tampilkan Activity sesuai dengan menu yang dipilih
     *
     */
    protected void tampilkanPilihan(String pilihan) {
        try {
            //Intent digunakan untuk sebagai pengenal suatu activity
            Intent i = null;
            if (pilihan.equals("Berita Terbaru")) {
                i = new Intent(this, PraBayar.class);
            } else if (pilihan.equals("Info Item")) {
                i = new Intent(this, PascaBayar.class);
            } else if (pilihan.equals("Customer Service")) {
                i = new Intent(this, CustomerService.class);
            } else if (pilihan.equals("Help")) {
                i = new Intent(this, Help.class);
            } else if (pilihan.equals("Exit")) {
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Anda Memilih: " + pilihan + " , Actionnya belum dibuat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and i want to add different image per list, so i mean is i want to add a.png to "Berita Terbaru", b.png to "Info Item", c.png "Customer Service" , so how to do it? i was very confused about this, thanks before...

Answer (score 1):

For achieving it you should make custom list view.  Please read the given tutorial link.

[Custom listview tutorial link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

I hope may answer help full to you.

Comment: i still dont understand... :(